# On the second floor(house structure)

Tags: grammar, prepositions

[image]

I need to be corrected of my **preposition usage**, not what the house is made of.(let's say I am describing my house's structure)

> I live in a house. A 2-storey house **in** a combination of wood and concrete, wood **on** the second floor and concrete **on** the lower level.

Are my *prepositions* here correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prepositions are correct. It is usual to write smaller numbers as words (up to ten in many style guides) including in forms like two-storey house (British spelling, 'story' US spelling). Another point: in American usage, the storey of a house at ground level is called the first floor, and the one above that the second floor, and so on. In British usage, the floors start at the ground floor, and the one above that is the first floor. If you wish to be consistent you should adopt either the British or American styles for these things.

https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-write-numbers

http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/storey_story.htm

http://speakspeak.com/about-english/ground-floors-and-first-floors-in-british-and-american-english

Comment: Wow this is a genius level of tips man, thx. All in all, I was almost completely correct only if the ''2-storey house'' was changed into ''two-storey house'' hehe(American writing style). Nice